# How to solve troubling for-loops and promises without async/await

Tags: node.js, for-loop, promise

I am struggling with for loops and promises without using async/await (this was not available on the version of azure functions I originally ran and I have not transferred all my code over to the newer version yet)
I am checking my database on json files, within each json I am looking to see if the URLs contained in 2 different arrays are still valid. 
Then if the url has expired I want to push that json id into a container to deal with later/update.

Currently I am struggling at the point of trying to test the 2 separate arrays per json.

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    getJsons(context, function(res) {
        createContainer(context, res)
    });
}

function getJsons(context, callback) {
    context.log('start');
    client.queryDocuments(
        collectionUrlJsons,
        `SELECT * FROM r`
    ).toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            context.log(err);
            context.done();
        } else {
            context.log(results.length + " jsons");
            // now I have all JSONs in an array
            analyse(context, results, function(result) {
                callback(result);
            })
        }
    });
}

function analyse(context, results) {
    var editArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var arr = [];
        var loopPhotos = checkPhotos(context, results[i].photos);
        var loopVideos = checkVideos(context, results[i].videos);
        Promise.all([loopPhotos, checkVideos]).then(function(result) {
            if (result[0].length > 0) {
                context.log('photos expired')
                arr.push('photo');
            }
            if (result[1].length > 0) {
                context.log('videos expired')
                arr.push('video');
            }
        });
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            editArr.push(results[i].id);
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(editArr);
}

function checkPhotos(context, photos) {
    var arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
        var link = photos[i].latestUrl;
        request(link, function(error, response, body) {

            if (response.statusCode == 403) {
                arr.push("photo: " + body);
            }

        });
    }
    return Promise.all(arr);
}

function checkVideos(context, videos) {
    var arr = [];

    context.log(videos)
    for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var link = videos[i].latestUrl;
        request(link, function(error, response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode == 403) {
                arr.push("video: " + body);
            }

        });
    }
    return Promise.all(arr);
}
function createContainer(context, jsons) {
    //code
}
```

Edit below to reflect comments - to put `if (arr.length >0)` inside `Promise.all` in `function analyse`:

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    getJsons(context, function(res) {
        createContainer(context, res)
    });
}

function getJsons(context, callback) {
    context.log('start');
    client.queryDocuments(
        collectionUrlJsons,
        `SELECT * FROM r`
    ).toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            context.log(err);
            context.done();
        } else {
            context.log(results.length + " jsons");
            // now I have all JSONs in an array
            analyse(context, results, function(result) {
                callback(result);
            })
        }
    });
}

function analyse(context, results) {
    var editArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var arr = [];
        var loopPhotos = checkPhotos(context, results[i].photos);
        var loopVideos = checkVideos(context, results[i].videos);
        Promise.all([loopPhotos, checkVideos]).then(function(result) {
            if (result[0].length > 0) {
                context.log('photos expired')
                arr.push('photo');
            }
            if (result[1].length > 0) {
                context.log('videos expired')
                arr.push('video');
            }
            if (arr.length > 0) {
                editArr.push(results[i].id);
            }
        });
    }
    return Promise.all(editArr);
}

function checkPhotos(context, photos) {
    var arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
        var link = photos[i].latestUrl;
        request(link, function(error, response, body) {

            if (response.statusCode == 403) {
                arr.push("photo: " + body);
            }

        });
    }
    return Promise.all(arr);
}

function checkVideos(context, videos) {
    var arr = [];

    context.log(videos)
    for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var link = videos[i].latestUrl;
        request(link, function(error, response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode == 403) {
                arr.push("video: " + body);
            }

        });
    }
    return Promise.all(arr);
}
function createContainer(context, jsons) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for help with at all.  The `checkVideos()` and `checkPhotos()` functions won't work at all.  They will return a promise that is already resolved to an empty array.  It's unclear why you'd call `Promise.all()` on an array of strings.  That doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I'm unsure how to make this work. I want `checkVideos()` and `checkPhotos()` to both finish looping `videos.length` and `photos.length`before resolving `arr` each, then when using both their results do the next part - which is not empty if a url has `403`. Which `Promise.all()` are you referring to not being useful?

Comment: The `Promise.all()` in those two functions.  If you just want help rewriting `checkVideos()` and `checkPhotos()` to work properly, I can do that.'

Comment: If you can that'd be helpful

Comment: Your code for those two functions has me confused.  If the `statusCode` is 403, you're trying to make a result of `"photo: " + body`, but what are you expecting the body to be if the response is 403?

Comment: ah i removed for simplicity it `body == URL signature expired` - that returns fine in context.log, so it gets there

Comment: You need to push *promises* to `editArr`, and you need to do it *immediately* during the loop, before calling `Promise.all(editArr)`.

Comment: @Bergi so I need to change what I push to `editArr` from `results[i].id`? What would I need to change it to in this case?

Comment: You need to push the `Promise.all([loopPhotos, checkVideos]).then(…)` promise. Doing `editArr.push(…)` inside the asynchronous `then` callback doesn't help anything, the `editArr` is empty when you call `Promise.all`

Comment: @bergi I am unsure how to do that given that I only want to push if `arr.length >0`

Comment: @JDT You can't - you always need to push the promise to be able to wait for it. After the outer `Promise.all`, you might however do any kind of post-processing to the results, such as filtering out empty arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version of `checkPhotos()` and `checkVideos()`:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

// returns promise that resolves to an array of 403 messages
// urls that don't respond with 403 don't put anything in the array
function checkUrls(context, urls, msg) {
    const promises = urls.map(item => {
        return rp({
          uri: item.latestUrl, 
          simple: false, 
          resolveWithFullResponse: true}
        ).then(response => {
            if (response.statusCode == 403) {
                return msg + response.body;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
        // remove null results from array
        return data.filter(item => item !== null);
    });
}

// returns promise that resolves to an array
function checkPhotos(context, photos) {
    return checkUrls(context, photos, "photo: ");
}

// returns promise that resolves to an array
function checkVideos(context, videos) {
    return checkUrls(context, photos, "video: ");
}
```

Here's the general idea:

1. Create a shared function since both `checkPhotos()` and `checkVideos()` are pretty much doing the same thing.
2. Use request-promise instead of request module because it returns a promise which makes it easier to coordinate multiple asynchronous operations.
3. Configure request-promise to return the whole response object so it can be used the same way you were using request
4. Filter out results that don't return 403 since your original code was only putting something in the result array if the request status was 403.  This doesn't seem particularly safe to me (like what about 404), but it's what your original code was doing.
5. Use `.map()` to easily generate an array of promises.
6. Use `Promise.all()` to know when the entire array of promises are all resolved.

P.S.

1. Your analyze function also needs to be rewritten.  Its logic is not correct.
2. `Promise.all()` expects you to pass it a **single argument that is an array of promises**.
3. You're passing a `context` variable around, but not using it.

Comment: Thanks for this - can you clarify why my analyse function logic is incorrect?

Comment: Hi sorry still unsure where my analyse is going wrong

Comment: @JDT.  You really need to go back to understanding some fundamentals about promises and `Promise.all()` and asynchronous operations.  When you get to this line of code`if (arr.length > 0) {` in your `analyze()` function, the `Promise.all().then()` handler will NOT have been called yet so your `arr` will ALWAYS be empty.  If you want to see that value, you have to examine it INSIDE the `.then()` handler.  That's the only place you can use it.

Comment: Ah yes I had corrected this in my code, putting `if (arr.length >0)` inside the promise and it still wouldn't work

Comment: ^^ editted to reflect your comment but still not  functioning as required

Comment: @JDT - Please don't continually change the code in your question because that means that answers don't correspond to the question anymore and it wrecks the Q/A as a long term reference for others.  If you need to show a new version of the code to show how you still have a problem after making suggested changes, then ADD a new version of your code to the question and make it very clear that this was added afterwards in response to feedback.  The original code from your question should remain.

Comment: Noted and Reverted

Comment: @JDT - It's too hard to figure out  what your code is actually trying  to accomplish to know how to rewrite analyze.  It seems pointless to just return an array of strings that say `'photo'` or `'video'` with no idea what goes with what URL.  So, what your code is currently coded to try to do (unsucessfully) doesn't seem useful so I don't feel like spending time rewriting yet another function for you.  In the future, please describe what the end result of your function should be (in words) and  then maybe people can help find a good way to achieve that.

Comment: @JDT - The point of my showing you how to rewrite two of your functions was for you to learn how to properly use an array of promises so you can then rewrite the rest of your code.  I'm not going to write all your code for you.